# How to specify order of execution of Java classes in a Selenium-Java Webdriver test project

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have to automate a test-suite for a web application which let user connect and sync with their Dropbox account. I am using Java Selenium Webdriver.

Here I have created test classes like this.

Class1.java - Test case to check if connected to Internet.

Class2.java-  Test case for sign in with Dropbox

Class3.java- Test case to verify if Dropbox folders are shown on web page.

Now these test classes are supposed to execute in this order.

But when I run the project as JUnit test, it executes these tests in some other order. I don't find any XML file so that I can specify order of execution of these classes.

I also have tried TestNG because I read [Here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xmle) that TestNG provides an attribute "preserve-order".

But It is not working. I don't have much experience with Selenium and Java Webdriver.

So any help would be appreciable.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JUnit test suite:

```
import org.junit.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Class1.class, Class2.class, Class3.class})
public class DropboxWorkflow {}
```

Comment: Thanx Peter. It works perfectly. Now I just need to run this java class and all specified java tests run as order specified in Suite.SuiteClasses.

Comment: One question please: if I have several test suites, is it possible to specify their execution order?

Answer (score 6):

[Peter Niederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser) is right.

In addition you can set the order of the tests to run within the classes (Junit 4.11):

```
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this can also be used. But I have to write only one test case in a class. That's why I didn't followed this approach.

Comment: The drawback of using `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` to control test execution order is that you'll have to play tricks with your test names (`aaa_doThis`, `bbb_doThat`, etc). However, it should be possible to write a method sorter that allows to number tests (e.g. with an annotation).

Answer (score 3):

Addition to Ittiel's post:

Instead of:
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
You can use:
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)

This way, you don't have to play tricks with your test names. You only have to arrange your tests in the correct order.

This works fine for me. Thanks to Ittiel!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Test(dataProvider = "Login", priority = 1)
public void login()
    {
     //code
    }

@Test(dataProvider = "Search", priority = 2)
public void search()
    {
     //code
    }
```